# Fast Linux Distro for High end Modern hardware

Tags: linux-distribution

I want linux distro recommendations for high performance..
I have a gaming laptop and I want to dual boot linux for educational purposes.
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS runs way slower and is laggy.
Is there any linux specifically designed for performance with no power saving.
I dont want to manually set up high performance in ubuntu.
My concern is not overboosting performance though, just normal performance which I expect to be high.

By the way, my specs are:
cpu - i7 8750h
gpu - nvidia gtx 1050ti
ram - 16gb

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure why this is happening. Ubuntu is fast even in budget computers. Try Fedora Gnome, it is a vanilla Linux version that can be expanded depends on your needs. Are you sure that you installed the GPU driver on Ubuntu? If you didn’t, I would recommend to give it another try.

Comment: i did install nvidia additional drivers which gave nvidia x prime application. On some other discussions i saw that ubuntu was in by default powersave mode. so i was seeing for a distro that didnt had this problem

Comment: Debian and Fedora with XFCE or MATE are the fastest you can try as a beginner. Don’t even bother with Gentoo or Arch.

Comment: i dont want a lightweight distro though, but i will try. by the way windows 10 runs damn fast as compared to ubuntu... also cpu speed in windows is upto 4ghz but in ubuntu when i tried the command /proc/cpuinfo the cpu speed was about 800mhz

Comment: This sounds to me like a driver issue. Maybe the drivers you used they are not optimized to use Turbo Boost and Hyper-Threading. I think that the GPU driver from the Nvidia website are better than the open source driver you downloaded. Gnome in a budget PC usually run as fast as a good tablet.

Comment: will it be better to install on virtualbox, because i think i have enough ram for that, i dont know much

Comment: Don’t even bother with virtual machines. It will not give you the real experience. They are good for testing functionality and nothing else. You can install Ubuntu core inside Windows 10. I use it a lot as it gives a native way to run a proper shell inside Windows.

Comment: Also try the latest 19.04 Ubuntu. This version supports up to the RX Vega M graphic cards and Intel Cannonlake.